# How to add data-attributes to <li> items of a <ul> menu in Drupal

Tags: html, drupal, drupal-7, fullpage.js, custom-data-attribute

This is such a great script called fullPage.js located here:  https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js

I managed to load the JavaScript file and CSS file and even with the Void Menu Module, managed to call anchor links, but I'm struggling with the data attributes part of the implementation of this code.

How do I get data-attributes to work in Drupal 7.25? I need to add them to the menu, so that the HTML looks something like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li data-menuanchor="firstPage"><a href="#firstPage">First slide</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage">Second slide</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="3rdPage"><a href="#3rdPage">Third slide</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="4thpage"><a href="#4thpage">Fourth slide</a></li>
</ul>
```

Just want to add it to the Main Menu in Drupal.  Any idea how?  Am trying to implement this on my homepage and using the Adaptive Sub-Theme with Display Suite Module installed, if that helps any.

Have added the following to template.php, but it makes no difference at all:

```
function MY_THEME_NAME_menu_link(&$variables) {
  $variables['element']['#attributes']['data-menuanchor'] = substr($variables['element']['href'], 1);
  return theme_menu_link($variables);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

You can download the sitemaniacs theme here:  http://dream-portal.net/dpdowns/MyProblem.zip
You can just download Adaptive Theme from Drupal [here](https://drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme) and than copy sitemaniacs to your sites/all/themes folder and than just enable the theme and go to your homepage.

There is also a folder called fullPage that is the example of it working perfectly fine without Drupal.

Files to take note of:

```
/sites/all/themes/sitemaniacs/scripts/custom.js
/sites/all/themes/sitemaniacs/template.php
/sites/all/themes/sitemaniacs/css/example2.css
/sites/all/themes/sitemaniacs/sitemaniacs.info
```

Let me know if you need anything else, k?

And Thank YOU!!!  What I've done is create 4 Basic Pages, and using the [Field Formatter Class Module](https://drupal.org/project/field_formatter_class) to give the body field a class (when managing the Display) defined as `section`, than promoted to front page.  Than I used HTML within another Node Type and used [NodeBlock Module](https://drupal.org/project/nodeblock) to output it as a menu item within the `Menu Bar` section of the blocks, with url `<front>`.  Let me know if you need anything else for this, but I can't get it to work using this simple approach.  I've tried tons of ways of doing it also, but no go for me.  If you find a method that works, or perhaps something is wrong somewhere else, please please let me know....  I'm pulling out my hair on this one.

Have tried straight HTML, and now getting this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined    jquery.fullPage.js?mzf0rp:506
scrollPage       jquery.fullPage.js?mzf0rp:506
doneResizing       jquery.fullPage.js?mzf0rp:889
```

The first error seems to occur in the `scrollPage` function on this line here:

```
var dtop = dest !== null ? dest.top : null;
```

Looks like `dest.top` is not defined on `.top`. Any idea why?

Comment: I can't get the damn thing to work, even with HTML.  Seems I am getting an undefined index of `.top` within the `jQuery.fullPage.js` file itself now.

Comment: Can you post your URL? If not, paste here the resulting HTML markup and the plugin initialization.

Comment: Not sure you want that, cause it's a shit load of code for just a simple thing to try and do in drupal!  I have tried different modules and tons of methods, I'm kinda even more lost than when I started with it. arggg!  But if you insist, I'll put together a URL for you, right now I'm building it in XAMMP

Comment: Right now I'm building it in XAMMP and quite frankly I don't want to go live with it yet...  So I'll copy paste HTML for you.

Comment: @Alvaro - I hope it's ok, I actually did one better and zipped up the entire theme using the Adaptive Theme as the Core.  Both the Core `Adaptive Theme` and the custom theme `sitemaniacs` can be found in the zip file.  I just zipped them both up along with an example of the fullPage.js working with plain HTML for reference if need be.  THANK YOU soooo very much!  It helps to have another set of eyes on this cause I've been at it all night long with this thing, but I'm not an experienced Drupal person either.  Cheers :)

Comment: @Alvaro - Updated with exact error message.

Comment: I believe you didn't understand me. When I was asking for the resulting HTML I was asking for the HTML code that you can see in your site when you click on "view source code" from the browser. I don't need all your files, just the generated HTML markup by your code as well as the plugin initialization that you are using.

Comment: @Alvaro - Thanks, but I figured it out and got it working finally! I believe that it was something else that got in the way of it working properly, something with Drupal, because when I split it into a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/tUKmN/ it works fine and so I removed a few Drupal modules that looked like it might have been causing a collision of some sort with it, and now it works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Menu Link Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_link_attributes) module that will let you add custom attributes per menu item.

Answer (score 0):

for "href" you can use `<'front'>#4thpage(front without any “cotation”)` in the path in menu that you create in Structure > Menus and use the [Menu Link Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_link_attributes) module for other attributes